# Understanding かと思えば in this context

Tags: grammar

> 天宮市の空に、幾つもの火花が散る。
>
> それは、あまりに現実離れした光景であった。
>
> 空には何隻もの巨大戦艦に無数の魔術師。羽虫のごとく視界を横切る影は、全てが人型を模した機械人形であった。
>
> 地上からは変形した建造物が引っ切りなしに砲撃を放ち、艦を攻撃している**かと思えば**、機械人形が精霊<ナイトメア>によって破壊されていく。

Does かと思えば mean “I thought... but it turned out to be different” in this context?
Or does かと思えば mean “not only... but also...” in this context?

I think it’s the latter. But I have a little doubt. My grammar book says when かと思えば mean “not only... but also...”, the formation should be かと思えば……も……. But there is no も after かと思えば in the quoted sentence.

Comment: How is 精霊<ナイトメア> related to 建造物 or its 砲撃 in that scene?

Comment: @aguijonazo 建造物s are on 精霊<ナイトメア>’s side and they are fighting their enemies, which are 敵艦 and 機械人形.

Comment: Then, it must mean “as soon as …” despite 〜ている. If Nightmare were attacking the same targets from a third place, it could mean “while A …, B …” Either way. I find the sentence a bit hard to read partly because of 〜いてる but also because the active and passive voices are mixed.

Answer (score 3):

This ～かと思えば means something happens right after something. Or in this context, it describes two things are happening almost at the same time.

- [Use of かと思ったら / かと思うと (in the context of as soon as, just when)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/75021/5010)
- [【JLPT N2 Grammar】〜かと思うと / 〜かと思えば / 〜かと思ったら](https://nihongo-net.com/2020/04/26/jlptn2-katoomouto/)
- [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar: かと思ったら/かと思うと (ka to omottara/ka to omou to)](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8A%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8A%E3%82%82%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8-ka-to-omottaraka-to-omou-to/)