# Please could someone explain かと思えば in this context?

Tags: grammar

In my textbook, there is only this very small explanation of this usage of かと思えば, and I can only find explanations online of it in the "No sooner than" context, like [here](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-ka-to-omottara-meaning/)

Below is the section from the textbook:

> 6)ロボットが登場するかと思えば、花も歌い出す。
> ＊いろいろあることを示す表現
> １このビルは中華料理店があるかと思えば、インド料理の店もある。
> ２公園にはジョギングをしている人もいるかと思えば、寝ている人もいる。

Please could someone explain かと思えば in this いろいろ sense?

Comment: Related/dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86451/45489

Comment: いろいろ means various (things) https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E8%89%B2%E8%89%B2/#je-4587